# Regex to match accents, spaces

Tags: php

How can I replace the text, for example: c2stackoverflow to

`span style="color:#ffdc50">stackoverflow</span>'`

I try to do this:

```
<?php

$string = "c2stackoverflow";    
$string = preg_replace("/c2([A-Za-záàâãéèêíïóôõöúçñÁÀÂÃÉÈÍÏÓÔÕÖÚÇÑ ])+$/", '<span style="color:#ffdc50">$1</span>', $string);    
echo $string;
```

But the output is:

```
<span style="color:#ffdc50">w</span>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your original regex shows (by its final `$`) that you want to replace the *entire* remainging set of characters after `c2`, you may simply use this:

```
$string = preg_replace("/c2(.*)$/", '<span style="color:#ffdc50">$1</span>', $string);
```

Note that I replaced `+` by `*` so even a string like `c2` will be replaced by `<span style="color:#ffdc50"></span>`.

Comment: Hi. Your example looks simple and clean, but doesn't work properly.

Comment: @AmandaThompson Don't mind, I discovered what was wrong. Try with my edited regex.

Comment: Hey! Take a look: If text looks like: http://prnt.sc/cmji5c the regex stop work. How can I fix?

Comment: @AmandaThompson As I highlighted in my answer, your initial need was cleary to replace **all characters** after `c2`. So your new example `<p>c2Super Stac</p>` gives `<p><span style="color:#ffdc50">Super Stac</p></span>`: **the regex didn't stop work**, it works as expected, but this example doesn't conform to the rules you implicitly established. For this example to work, you must establish new, different rules. E.g. in this peculiar case the regex might be something like `/c2([^<]*)/` (note the absence of the final `$` now).

Answer (score 1):

Just replace plus symbol like this:

```
$string = preg_replace("/c2([A-Za-záàâãéèêíïóôõöúçñÁÀÂÃÉÈÍÏÓÔÕÖÚÇÑ ]+)$/", '<span style="color:#ffdc50">$1</span>', $string);
```